# Load angular template on some event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm quite new to angular and frontend in general, but what i'd like to see is something similar to what routing with `ngView` gives, but without routing, i.e just load a template on some event. To be more specific, let's say i have an input field somewhere in the header and when i click/focus on this field a special panel with different input options shows up. The trick is that this input field and other elements are already a part of a template which is loaded into `ngView`, so as i understand i can't use another `ngView` for options pane.

Comment: You can use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) - a much more powerful alternative to `ngRoute`. Also, look into using `ng-include` to load a template based on some scope variable.

Comment: @NewDev is it possible to animate how the template shows up in `ngInclude` or it just inserts html?

Comment: @4lex1v you can setup animations for ngShow/ngHide, and then they get animated automatically when you attach the class to your element that gets hidden/shown. You will need the angular-animate module for this

Comment: @4lex1v, yes, there are `enter` and `leave` animations for `ng-include`

Answer (score 0):

use ngIf, ngShow, ngHide, ngSwitch for stuff like that

```
<button ng-click="showStuff = true">Show Stuff</button>
<button ng-click="showStuff = false">Hide Stuff</button>
<div ng-show="showStuff">Showing Stuff</div>
<div ng-hide="showStuff">Hiding Stuff</div>
```

Have a look at [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tm3tTLP9euAvEfnCqXDx?p=preview) for a quick and dirty, working example.

Note that the showStuff variable is just magically created by angular on the root scope, since I'm not using a controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can load templates with ng-if and ng-include like this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/n8TV4x?p=info):

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div class='container'>
    <button ng-click='tmpl = true' class='btn btn-info'>Load template!</button>
    <div ng-if='tmpl'>
      <div ng-include="'template.html'"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The ngIf directive will add element to the DOM when the argument expression is true. Then, the angular will compile the inner directive ngInclude, loading the template.